# Why did Google remove Image API for App Engine running Python 3.7?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-3.7, responsive-images

I am using Google Cloud Storage and I want to serve scaled images from it, Python 2 version of Google App Engine supported it via Images API but with Python3, they removed that API.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences

Cannot understand the intension behind removing such an import feature, upgrading to Python3 in Google Cloud environment sounds like a downgrade to me.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the proprietary [App Engine APIs are not available in Python3.7](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#app_engine_apis). The main reason is because GCP is unbundling App Engine and now, you are no longer dependent on these APIs.

Currently, there are some third parties alternative solutions. In your specific case, and based on [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#images), I think that you can try to use Imgix or Rethumb.

Comment: Very sad to see the Image API go. It was one of the few differentiatiors GCS had to S3.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Google is planning on adding it back to Python 3:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/access

> To reduce runtime migration complexity, Google Cloud now supports a set of App Engine bundled services and their associated APIs on second-generation runtimes, which include Python 3, Java 11, and Go 1.12 or higher. Your app can call bundled services APIs for second-generation runtimes through language-idiomatic libraries.